# Pixel raw image format for icon

Tags: c++, image, icons, sdl

I started to develop a game using SDL 2 library and faced a problem: I specified icon in Visual Studio, but SDL_Window's icon doesn't change. I found this code on SDL wiki:

```
SDL_Surface *surface;     // Declare an SDL_Surface to be filled in with pixel data from an image file
        Uint16 pixels[16 * 16] = {  // ...or with raw pixel data:
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff,
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff,
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff,
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff,
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff,
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff,
            0x0fff, 0x0aab, 0x0789, 0x0bcc, 0x0eee, 0x09aa, 0x099a, 0x0ddd,
            0x0fff, 0x0eee, 0x0899, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x1fff, 0x0dde, 0x0dee,
            0x0fff, 0xabbc, 0xf779, 0x8cdd, 0x3fff, 0x9bbc, 0xaaab, 0x6fff,
            0x0fff, 0x3fff, 0xbaab, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x6689, 0x6fff, 0x0dee,
            0xe678, 0xf134, 0x8abb, 0xf235, 0xf678, 0xf013, 0xf568, 0xf001,
            0xd889, 0x7abc, 0xf001, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0bcc, 0x9124, 0x5fff,
            0xf124, 0xf356, 0x3eee, 0x0fff, 0x7bbc, 0xf124, 0x0789, 0x2fff,
            0xf002, 0xd789, 0xf024, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0002, 0x0134, 0xd79a,
            0x1fff, 0xf023, 0xf000, 0xf124, 0xc99a, 0xf024, 0x0567, 0x0fff,
            0xf002, 0xe678, 0xf013, 0x0fff, 0x0ddd, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0xb689,
            0x8abb, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0xf001, 0xf235, 0xf013, 0x0fff, 0xd789,
            0xf002, 0x9899, 0xf001, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0xe789,
            0xf023, 0xf000, 0xf001, 0xe456, 0x8bcc, 0xf013, 0xf002, 0xf012,
            0x1767, 0x5aaa, 0xf013, 0xf001, 0xf000, 0x0fff, 0x7fff, 0xf124,
            0x0fff, 0x089a, 0x0578, 0x0fff, 0x089a, 0x0013, 0x0245, 0x0eff,
            0x0223, 0x0dde, 0x0135, 0x0789, 0x0ddd, 0xbbbc, 0xf346, 0x0467,
            0x0fff, 0x4eee, 0x3ddd, 0x0edd, 0x0dee, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0dee,
            0x0def, 0x08ab, 0x0fff, 0x7fff, 0xfabc, 0xf356, 0x0457, 0x0467,
            0x0fff, 0x0bcd, 0x4bde, 0x9bcc, 0x8dee, 0x8eff, 0x8fff, 0x9fff,
            0xadee, 0xeccd, 0xf689, 0xc357, 0x2356, 0x0356, 0x0467, 0x0467,
            0x0fff, 0x0ccd, 0x0bdd, 0x0cdd, 0x0aaa, 0x2234, 0x4135, 0x4346,
            0x5356, 0x2246, 0x0346, 0x0356, 0x0467, 0x0356, 0x0467, 0x0467,
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff,
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff,
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff,
            0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff, 0x0fff
        };
        surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(pixels, 16, 16, 16, 16 * 2, 0x0f00, 0x00f0, 0x000f, 0xf000);

        // The icon is attached to the window pointer
        SDL_SetWindowIcon(wind, surface);

        // ...and the surface containing the icon pixel data is no longer required.
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
```

My question is "**What exactly Uint16 pixels contains and how do I can get this data from image(.ico, .bmp)?**"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19336160/366904, https://caedesnotes.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/how-to-integrate-your-sdl2-window-icon-or-any-image-into-your-executable/

Comment: From SDL_image's site: "SDL_image is an image file loading library. It loads images as SDL surfaces and textures, and supports the following formats: BMP, GIF, JPEG, LBM, PCX, PNG, PNM, TGA, TIFF, WEBP, XCF, XPM, XV". So, .ico files are not supported. For .bmp files, you don't even have to use SDL_image, the core part includes the .bmp loading functions.